# Lambda in VPC access RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc

I am attempting to make a lambda which will shut down an RDS instance on a schedule. I put my lambda in my VPC because I thought it would not need Internet access. However, I'm trying to use boto3 to access the instance, and I'm getting an error.

```
rds = boto3.client('rds')
dbs = rds.describe_db_instances()

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    try:
        # get all of the db instances
        for db in dbs['DBInstances']:
            print ("%s@%s:%s %s") % (
            db['MasterUsername'],
            db['Endpoint']['Address'],
            db['Endpoint']['Port'],
            db['DBInstanceStatus'])

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

However, when boto3 tries to connect RDS, I'm getting this error.

```
[ERROR] ConnectTimeoutError: Connect timeout on endpoint URL: "https://rds.us-east- 
2.amazonaws.com/"
```

This looks to me like boto3 is trying to call a URL on the internet. I can't tell if the lambda cannot get out of the VPC or what. Is there no way to just reach within AWS and get to the instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should *not* attach the AWS Lambda function to a VPC because it does not need to access any resources in the VPC.

The API calls being made to the Amazon RDS service are being sent to an endpoint on the Internet, not within the VPC. The Amazon RDS service will then turn the database on/off.

By *not* specifying a VPC for the Lambda function, it will have direct access to the Internet and the calls will succeed.

Answer (score 2):

If you do want your Lambda in a VPC for extra security (or other reasons), there are two options I can think of for connecting to RDS: 1) Making it capable of reaching the public internet; or 2) Making it connect to RDS without leaving the AWS Network. You can even use both depending on your use cases (I'll explain the differences later).

For both solutions, first you need to figure which **subnets** and **security group** is linked to your lambda:

[image: Lambda screen]

### Solution 1. Associate Elastic IPs to the Lambda's Network Interfaces

Next, go to EC2 Service, find the **Public IPs** menu under **Network & Security**. Allocate one IP for each subnet (in the example above there are two subnets).

Go to **Network Interfaces** menu, find the network interfaces attached to your lambda (same subnet and security group).

[image: Network Interfaces]

Associate the Public IPs in the actions menu for each one:

[image: Actions menu]

[image: Associate IP]

### Solution 2. Create a VPC Endpoint for RDS

Go to VPC Service in the console, open the **Endpoints** menu option under **Virtual private cloud**. Click the **Create Endpoint** button on top.

[image: VPC Endpoints]

Choose the AWS Service you want to connect (e.g. RDS, S3, Secrets Manager), select the VPC your lambda is in:

[image: Create Endpoint 1]

Select the subnets (based on the AZ) and Security Group your lambda is linked to:

[image: Create Endpoint 2]

Do this for each AWS Service your Lambda needs access to (e.g. RDS, S3, etc).

### Explanation and How to choose one

Your Lambda loses access to public internet when inside a VPC, so you can't fetch data from external services/APIs, which includes most AWS Services because connection is made via public internet.

Solution 1 will make your Lambda capable of reaching public internet again, which is convenient.

Solution 2 will make your Lambda capable of connecting to AWS Services without leaving the AWS Network, which reduces latency and improves security.

If your lambda only needs access to RDS and a few other AWS Services, you can go with solution 2. If your lambda needs to access external APIs (unrelated to AWS), you need solution 1, but even in that case you could mix them and use solution 2 for better security and reduced latency, so you can use both.